# How to pass a Optional List of User bean to JsonParser to generate PDF

Tags: spring-boot, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I'm trying to generate a PDF from my Spring boot application. I'm using itextpdf and pdfbox for the same. I'm fetching the required user details in an `Optional<List<User>> bean`. How do I convert/pass this bean to my JsonParser which accepts only Strings?

This is what I've tried so far

Controller :-

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM;
import static javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status;
import static org.apache.http.HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST;
import static org.apache.http.HttpStatus.SC_OK;

@Slf4j
@EnableLogging
@Path("/UserDetails")
public class UserDetails {

    @GET
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response execute() throws WebApplicationException, FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

        Optional<List<User>> user = DAO.getUsers();



        if (user.isPresent()) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement je = jp.parse("Some String");
            String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("myJSON.pdf"));

            document.open();
            Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk(prettyJsonString, font);

            document.add(chunk);
            document.close();
            return status(SC_OK).entity(user).build();
        } else {
            return status(SC_BAD_REQUEST).entity(user).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any PDFBox code, so why the label?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to convert your java object to JSON string, you can do this in this way:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(yourObj);
```

Bear in mind that `gson` has a plenty of options for how the output will be formatted during the serialization process.

Comment: `user` is the object I want to convert to JSON string. But I'm getting an error while doing the same. I'm doing what you suggested in the code above. Check the following line :- `String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);` . The problem I'm looking to solve is to convert my `Optional<List<User>>` bean to a String. I need help with that part. The rest of the code works fine.

Comment: "But I'm getting an error while doing the same." => include that error in your question, and some of the stack trace. (you can edit your question)

Comment: @cyberman123 Pass `user` variable to `toJson` method: `String jsonInString = gson.toJson(user);` but before check if value in optional is present. If you're sure just do `String jsonInString = gson.toJson(user.get());`